# Apache Jena Fuseki has clustering or Auto scaling support?

Tags: jena, fuseki

We are using Apache Jena Fuseki (2.4), and I just thought of checking whether it has auto scaling, clustering, or other high availability options.

We have built all our services as micro services (stateless) and deployed in Docker and k8s environment with auto scaling enabled based on CPU and memory load. Although micro services are enabled with scaling, backend operations go through Fuseki, which acts as a single point of failure when "n" number of users are hitting the application.

In summary, the question is if Fuseki has any support for clustering or auto scaling?

Comment: Asked and answered on the Jena user list : https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/rd20db2976846fffb745b28f5e41e466f210523d6b34afe321a01a5ae%40%3Cusers.jena.apache.org%3E

Comment: I only see the question in the link